# How to write only "if" condition in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

Say I have 2 strings "Jack" & "Jones". I print ""jack" but "Jones" will be printed if some condition gets true
Like

```
"Jack"
if(condition)
+ "& Jones".
```

In jasper

```
<![CDATA[ 
                      "Jack" + ($P{condition}.equals(Boolean.TRUE))
                                                " & Jones" 
 ]]>
```

Can you help me with the syntax for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 "Jack" + ($P{condition}.equals(Boolean.TRUE)? " & Jones" : "")
```

Comment: Can You post your jrxml. I have this `"Jack" + ($P{test} == true ? " & Jones": "")` in an empty report and it works